# Viewing Load Test Results in Web Browser/SSRS

Tags: testing, reporting-services, tfs, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

Is there a way to view the Load test results (i.e. Load Test Summary) from Visual Studio in a web browser or generate it with the Reporting Services?

I am wondering also if there is a nice way to generate SSRS templates for comparing tests runs, like it is possible in excell add-in?

Many thanks,
Wojtek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

http://loadtestreports.codeplex.com/

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged (links tend to get stale over time).
Please consider editing your answer and adding a synopsis here.